# Gaining access to package-access members by creating the same package name

Tags: java, inheritance, package

I have a question about a sneaky way to gain access to package-access members that occurred to me.  Specifically, I want to extend a class - let's call it `com.acme.Foo` - to add some functionality.  This is pure addition: all current methods of `Foo` would be supported just by delegating to the superclass's method.  However, there is no accessible constructor of `Foo`, so I can't extend the class and my implementation won't pass the "isA" test for being a `Foo`.  There is no interface that expresses `Foo`-ness that I can use instead of inheritance.

This is where the sneaky thought occurred to me: `Foo` has a package-access constructor, so why not just create a package `com.acme` in my source folder and create an `InheritableFoo` class in that package:

```
package com.acme;

public class InheritableFoo extends Foo {
    public InheritableFoo() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Now I can implement my extension to `Foo` by extending `InheritableFoo`, since that DOES have an accessible constructor.

This feels all wrong, and somehow unethical: I'm not respecting the decision the original programmer made when he or she decided to not expose a constructor for `Foo`.  But it could be the case that they simply adopted the "deny everything until there's a reason for it" approach.  Either way, is there anything fundamentally wrong with this idea? Am I going to cause myself problems in the future if I go this route, and if so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct regarding the fact that you can "sneak" in a class of your own into another package and get access to package restricted elements.

This will however only as long as the author of `com.acme.foo` distribute his code as source or an unsealed package. Should the author of this package distribute it as a sealed jar (which is quite common I believe) your approach will no longer work.

From [Sealing Packages within a JAR File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html)

> Packages within JAR files can be optionally sealed, which means that
>   all classes defined in that package must be archived in the same JAR
>   file.